# php multi lang site clean url

Tags: php, url, global-variables, clean-urls

I'm developing a multilang site. The content generated on the varible that passes in the url. Exemple for about us page my url is: domain.com/file.php?id=1 I got one main file and in that file the query gets the id of the selected menu.

If I change the language my url turns to domain.com/file.php?id=1&lang=en. Every time I change the language my url adds one more lang like this: domain.com/file.php?id=1&lang=en&lang=fr&lang=de&lang=en.....

in other multilang project I used this: `header("location: ".$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);` But the it were less dynamic pages. like this: domains.com/aboutus.php. I mean: the number of pages were static. The user cannot add or remove pages.

This time  because I pass the page id in the url I tried `header("location: ".$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'].'?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);` but it gives an redirect cycle error every time I try to change the lang.

**UPDATE**

**Code to select the languages:**

```
<?php $actual= $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]."?".$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];?>

<div id="langContainer">
    <span><a <?php if ($_SESSION['idLang']=='en') {echo"class='active'";}?> href="<?php echo $actual ?>&lang=en">EN</a></span>
    <span><a <?php if ($_SESSION['idLang']=='fr') {echo"class='active'";}?> href="<?php echo $actual ?>&lang=fr">FR</a> </span>
    <span><a <?php if ($_SESSION['idLang']=='es') {echo"class='active'";}?> href="<?php echo $actual ?>&lang=es">ES</a></span>
    <span><a <?php if ($_SESSION['idLang']=='de') {echo"class='active'";}?> href="<?php echo $actual ?>&lang=de">DE</a></span>
</div>
```

in my **session.php**

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["idLang"]) )
    $_SESSION["idLang"] = 'en';

if (@isset($_GET["lang"])){
    $_SESSION["idLang"] = $_GET['lang'];

    //header("location: ".$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'].'?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

}
```

So my question is if there's anyway I can get my url cleaner, hidding the lang variables?

Thanks

Comment: if you want a clean url, use url rewriting. You then can have a url like this: `domain.com/en/file/1`. If you want to change the language you can use a regex to replace en with the new language while keeping the rest of the path.

Comment: How are you constructing these URLs? Just *replace* the `lang` parameter at that time instead of appending another one.

Comment: @deceze I Updated the post with additional code.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically build query parameters, *replacing* exiting ones in the current URL:

```
<a href="...?<?php echo http_build_query(array('lang' => 'foo') + $_GET); ?>">
```